# Rails avoid writing attribute of nested object to log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, nested-attributes

How can I prevent a certain parameter of a nested relationship in rails from entering the log file - I am writing LARGE files to a column in the db and don't want rails to write that to the log file.. I know of **filter_parameter_logging** but it doesn't seem to work for nested models - I may just be putting in the wrong spot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Rails code this should work even for nested parameter hashes.
You can implement the filter_parameters method on your controller to work around your issue. Read [this](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/124137) thread for more details.
I have posted the code from the thread above for your convenience.

```
  def filter_parameters(unfiltered)
    return unfiltered unless params[:action]  == 'payment'
    filtered = unfiltered.dup
    filtered[:creditcard] = unfiltered[:creditcard].dup
    filtered[:creditcard][:number] = '[FILTERED]'
    filtered[:creditcard][:type] = '[FILTERED]'
    filtered
  end
```