# Class filter_parameters method on controllers getting Hash instead of HashWithIndifferentAccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I started getting this problem after upgrading to Rails 3.2.13.

I have this filter_parameters method override in my controller like so

```
class Api::OrdersController < ApiController
  before_filter :protect_api

  def filter_parameters(unfiltered)
    filtered[:credit_card] = unfiltered[:credit_card].dup
    filtered[:credit_card][:number] = '[FILTERED]'
    filtered[:credit_card][:type] = '[FILTERED]'
    filtered
  end
```

and in my spec I have this

```
put "/api/orders/#{order.number}",{credit_card: {
                                          number: '424242466624242',
                                          month: 9,
                                          year: Time.now.year + 1,
                                          first_name: 'bob',
                                          last_name: 'Joe',
                                          verification_value: '123',
                                          type: 'visa'
                                },
```

When I run the spec I get an error

```
Failure/Error: put "/api/orders/#{order.number}",{credit_card: {
     TypeError:
       can't dup NilClass
```

So I traced it down to this line where

```
unfiltered[:credit_card].dup
puts unfiltered.class #Hash
```

And since its a Hash it can't find the value with the symbolized key.

So I tried this,

```
def filter_parameters(unfiltered)
    unfiltered = unfiltered.with_indifferent_access
    filtered = unfiltered.dup
    filtered[:credit_card] = unfiltered[:credit_card].dup
    filtered[:credit_card][:number] = '[FILTERED]'
    filtered[:credit_card][:type] = '[FILTERED]'
    filtered
end
```

But the filter_parameters method seems to be running twice, and the second time the unfiltered param looked like this :-

```
{"session_id"=>"c050d509b93f28d10b81976fcaf02d81", "timezone"=>"pst"}
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: why dont you add your params to `config.filter_parameters`?

Comment: i followed the instructions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308891/rails-avoid-writing-attribute-of-nested-object-to-log

Comment: but let me double check again if filter_parameters works with nested attributes

Comment: nope ... tried the following ... doesn't work :/

config.filter_parameters += [:credit_card][:number]